# Installing scikits.samplerate fails

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, scikits

I'd like to use "scikits.samplerate", but installation fails.
I'm using Windows10 (64 Bits) for Python 3.51 with Anaconda.

Firstly, I followed this instruction:
https://scikits.appspot.com/samplerate

```
>pip install scikits.samplerate Collecting scikits.samplerate   Using cached scikits.samplerate-0.3.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    SamplerateInfo:
      libraries samplerate not found in c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib
      libraries samplerate not found in C:\
      libraries samplerate not found in c:\users\username\anaconda3\libs
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "scikits\samplerate\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        sf_config = sf_info.get_info(2)
      File "c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py", line 568, in get_info
        raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: Some third-party program or library is not found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9sjnkaf5\scikits.samplerate\setup.py", line 74, in <module>
        classifiers = CLASSIFIERS,
      File "c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9sjnkaf5\scikits.samplerate\setup.py", line 59, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage(DISTNAME)
      File "c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scikits\samplerate\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        [samplerate].""")
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: SRC (http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/) library not found.  Directories to search
    for the libraries can be specified in the site.cfg file, in section
    [samplerate].

    ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9sjnkaf5\scikits.samplerate\
```

... Next, I followed this instruction:
https://anaconda.org/hcc/scikits.samplerate

```
>conda install -c hcc scikits.samplerate=0.3.3 Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org Fetching package metadata: ...... Solving package specifications: . Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - scikits.samplerate 0.3.3*

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda scikits.samplerate 0.3.3*
```

... so, I serached:

```
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\username>anaconda search -t conda scikits↲ Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org↲ Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:↲ Packages:↲
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms↲
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------↲
     HCC/scikits.samplerate    |    0.3.3 | conda           | linux-64↲
                                          : A python module for high quality audio resampling↲
     anaconda/scikits-image    |    0.7.1 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, win-64, linux-32, osx-64↲
     davidbgonzalez/scikits.talkbox |    0.2.5 | conda           | linux-64↲
     desilinguist/scikits-bootstrap |    0.3.1 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64↲
     krisvanneste/scikits.timeseries |   0.91.3 | conda           | win-64↲
     lukepfister/scikits.cuda  | master_2016.2 | conda           | linux-64↲
                                          : Python interface to GPU-powered libraries↲
     menpo/scikits.sparse      |      0.2 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64↲
     miguelalexanderdiaz/scikits.cuda |  0.5.0b1 | conda           | linux-64↲
                                          : Python interface to GPU-powered libraries↲
     poppy-project/scikits.samplerate |    0.3.3 | conda           | linux-armv7l↲
                                          : Simple Hamming Marker Detection using OpenCV↲
     rgrout/scikits.bootstrap  |    0.3.2 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64↲
                                          : Bootstrap confidence interval estimation routines for SciPy.↲ Found 10 packages↲ ↲ [Anaconda3] C:\Users\username>anaconda show poppy-project/scikits.samplerate↲ Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org↲ Name:    scikits.samplerate↲ Summary: Simple Hamming Marker Detection using OpenCV↲ Access:  public↲ Package Types: conda↲ Versions:↲    + 0.3.3↲ ↲ To install this package with conda run:↲
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/poppy-project scikits.samplerate↲ ↲ [Anaconda3] C:\Users\username>conda install
--channel https://conda.anaconda.org/poppy-project scikits.samplerate↲ Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org↲ Fetching package metadata: ......↲ Solving package specifications: .↲ Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:↲
  - scikits.samplerate↲ ↲ You can search for this package on anaconda.org with↲ ↲
    anaconda search -t conda scikits.samplerate↲
```

... I have done what I was told, but still it fails.
Does anyone have a solution?
Is this really installable?

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/cournape/samplerate/issues/8

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if this would work, but glad if it does. Have you tried to edit the site.cfg file and try the installation again.This is what line 20 error in your question says as well.

The user here has done it on Ubuntu, maybe a similar approach works for Windows as well.

http://msnoise.org/doc/installation.html

```
You first need to install the SRC library:

sudo apt-get install libsamplerate0 libsamplerate0-dev
This python package will probably be the most tricky to install. If you are lucky, you can just

pip install scikits.samplerate
On my Ubuntu 12.04, this results in an error because the SRC library path is not found. The reason is that the setup searches SRC in /usr/lib and not in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu where the library is actually present. To install, you need to download the archive from pypi and edit some configuration file:

wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikits.samplerate/scikits.samplerate-0.3.3.tar.gz#md5=96c8d8ba3aa95a9db15994f78792efb4
tar -xvf scikits.samplerate-0.3.3.tar.gz
cd scikits.samplerate-0.3.3
then edit the site.cfg example file and insert the following lines:

[samplerate]
library_dirs=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
include_dirs=/usr/include
To know where the SRC library is on you machine:

sudo dpkg -L libsamplerate0
sudo dpkg -L libsamplerate0-dev
then, build and install:

python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the info is not enough.

I downloaded "scikits.samplerate-0.3.3.tar.gz" from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.samplerate. Extracted the tar and put it under C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\pkgs (I'm not sure if this is the right place). I modified "site.cfg.example" as you said.
However, there is no dpkg command since I'm not using Ubuntu. It seems that a solution for Ubuntu cannot be a solution of Windows this time. Thanks, though.

Comment: i assume u used the file explorer to navigate to the path of SRC library(the windows equivalent of finding the path) and then replaced with path in windows format C:\users\Program files x 86\anaconda\lib (or like that) rather than using the one in the example. Sorry it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, notice I used UNIX system, not Windows.

I had same/similar error:

> ...numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: SRC
>   (http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/) library not found.  Directories to
>   search
>       for the libraries can be specified in the site.cfg file, in section...

I followed link given in it, found download site:
http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/download.html

- downloaded sources,
- compiled and installed them
- then just installed scikits.samplerate using pip

In Windows it might be more difficult (i haven't tried it!), but on the site there is a link to instructions for Windows: http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/win32.html

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but again, a Linux solution cannot be a Windows solution. I already tried it (to compile the source code with Visual Studio C++) and it didn't work at all. Please check this author's profile. He is a real Windows-hater. He didn't compile the Windows version on purpose. He asked money to compile for Windows without saying how much is enough. If we pay more, he work harder. That's it. I don't need this bullshit any more.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos7 when I had that error I did:

```
yum install libsamplerate-devel libsamplerate
```

Answer (score -1):

For Windows I am using Miniconda2 and in order to get librosa to work installed ffmpeg using this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```